# Flask-Login | url query string arg 'next'

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Auth blueprint login route:

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if request.method == 'POST':
    doctor_id = request.form.get('doctor-id')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    docktor = session.query(Doctor).filter_by(doctor_health_id=int(doctor_id)).first()

    if docktor:
        if docktor.verify_password(password):
            login_user(user=docktor)
            flash("Login Successful", "ok")
            login_user(docktor)

            _next = request.args.get('next')

            print(_next)
            if _next is None or not _next.startswith('/'):
                _next = url_for("medic.home")
                print(_next)
                return redirect(url_for('medic.home'))

        else:
            flash('wrong password')
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    else:
        flash('Wrong credentials')
        return url_for('auth.login')

else:
    return render_template('auth/login.html')
```

Medic Blueprint home route:

```
@medic.route('/')
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template('medic/home.html')
```

So my problem is that i try to log in user using Flask-Login.... but I can't solve problem that my login route send me to

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login?next=%2Fmedic%2F
```

this url...

I can not figure what am I doing wrong here...

I read docs from Flask and Flask-Login and search on stackoverflow but solutions that i fund did not work for me..
How do I solve that query string problem?

request log is:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2021 11:18:37] "POST /auth/login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2021 11:18:37] "GET /medic/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2021 11:18:37] "GET /auth/login?next=%2Fmedic%2F             
HTTP/1.1" 200 -`
```

Comment: Have you tried `redirect(url_for('login'))` ?

Comment: Well I need redirect from login route to home page that is medic blueprint
127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login ---> 127.0.0.1:5000/medic/home, but that 'next's url is making problems for me

Comment: Just use the method name in the `url_for`.  like change `redirect(url_for('auth.login'))` to `redirect(url_for('login'))`, and same for `medic.home` to `home` and tell us

Comment: Look, my problem is http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login?next=%2Fmedic%2F query string and next parameter from flask-login.... i did redirects in the past applications and i understand redirects and url_for, but maybe don't understand that 'next' and how to solve that is a normal url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an else statement for the case that _next startswith '/'
In your case _next starts with '/' (or is None) and your given code goes to the return at the bottom:

```
return render_template('auth/login.html')
```

using the existing _next as arg inside the url, that is why it sends you to

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login?next=%2Fmedic%2F
```

So complete the following part of your code with an else statement, othwerise it will send you at the return statement at the bottom (`return render_template('auth/login.html')`) every time your current condition is not met:

```
if _next is None or not _next.startswith('/'):
                _next = url_for("medic.home")
                print(_next)
                return redirect(url_for('medic.home'))
```